# Optimization problem: Computing the gradient

Tags: numerical-optimization

I need help with the following exercise:

Solve $\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)$, where $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$. We define the inner product $(v,w)_A:= v^TAw$, induced by a positive definite and symmetric matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$.

First compute the gradient $\nabla^Af(x)$ with respect to the inner product defined by $(\nabla^Af(x),v)_A=\partial f(x)(v) \forall v\in\mathbb{R}^d$

Ok, so I´m not sure if I have to solve the following equation $(\nabla^Af(x),v)_A=(\nabla^Af(x))^TAv=\partial f(x)(v)$.If yes how exactly?
Or is there an easier way?

Comment: You don't have to solve that equation; that is the *definition* of $\nabla^A f$. In order to do the minimization, you have to solve for $\nabla^A f=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make it clear. Given $f\in C^1(\mathbb R^n;\mathbb R^k)$, the [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#In_higher_dimensions), [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative), [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative), [differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_(infinitesimal)), [total differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Differentials_in_several_variables), [pushforward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)), however you call it, of $f$ at a point $x$ is the linear map
$$
df_x=Df_x=f'(x)=\frac{df}{dx}:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^k
$$
such that
$$
f(y)-f(x)-df_x(y-x) = o(|y-x|) .
$$
In the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^k$, the derivative is represented by the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) $J_f(x)$.

In the case of a scalar function, $k=1$ and the derivative is a linear map $df_x:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$, that is, an element of the dual space $(\mathbb R^n)^*$.

If you fix a [non-degenerate bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondegenerate_form) $B:\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R:(v,w)\mapsto B(v,w)$, then for every linear functional $\phi\in(\mathbb R^n)^*$ there is a vector $v_\phi\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $\phi(w)=B(v_\phi,w)$ for all $w\in\mathbb R^n$.

The [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Gradient_and_the_derivative_or_differential) is the vector that represents the derivative with respect to a chosen non-degenerate form.

In our case, the linear functional that we want to represent is the derivative $df_x$ and the bilinear form is $B(v,w)=\langle Av,w\rangle=v^TAw$, where $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and $\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle$ is the standard scalar product.

If $\nabla f(x)=J_f(x)$ denotes the standard gradient (the one with respect to the standard scalar product), then
$$
\nabla^A f(x) = A^{-1}\nabla f(x)
$$
is the vector you are looking for. In fact,
$$
B(\nabla^Af(x),w)=\langle A\nabla^Af(x),w\rangle
=\langle AA^{-1}\nabla f(x),w\rangle
=\langle \nabla f(x),w\rangle = df_x(w).
$$

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain what exactly he doesn't understand of this laborious, in-depth and accurate answer?